# Parantheses around RHS in Python assignment

Tags: python

I am working on a Python code with many lines like this:

```
local_var = ( SomeClass(arg1, arg2) )
local_var.method1( )
```

i.e. there are parens around the assignment. What is the purpose of this? Personally I would just have written:

```
local_var = SomeClass(arg1, arg2)
local_var.method1( )
```

Comment: IMO, there is no difference between them. I prefer the latter.

Comment: Apprt from difficult readability of code there is no purpose